# How count instances of keywords in a list through pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I can't figure out how to get python to count each of the instances of each keyword and put them in a list "count_of_occ". It will output to one row.

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import requests
keywords = ["Goulds", "Pump", "http"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': keywords})
URL = ["https://www.gouldspumps.com/en-US/Home/"]
for r in URL:
    ctnt=requests.get(r, verify=False)
output_content = str(ctnt.content)
count_of_occ = [0 for i in keywords]
for num in count_of_occ:
    for i in keywords:
        if i in output_content:
            count_of_occ[num] += output_content.count(i)
df['Occurence'] = pd.Series(count_of_occ, index=df.index)
print(df)
```

```
Output:
  Keyword  Occurence
0  Goulds        429
1    Pump          0
2    http          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates the issue:

```py
count_of_occ = [0, 0, 0]

for num in count_of_occ:
    count_of_occ[num] += 5

print(count_of_occ)
```

you might expect the above to output `[5, 5, 5]`, but it'll actually print `[15, 0, 0]`. The for-loop has 3 iterations, but since it's iterating through `[0, 0, 0]`, `num` is always `0` so `count_of_occ[num]` is always the first list item.

Here's a script that accomplishes what you're looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

keywords = ["Goulds", "Pump", "http"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': keywords})
URL = ["https://www.gouldspumps.com/en-US/Home/"]
for r in URL:
    ctnt = requests.get(r, verify=False)
output_content = str(ctnt.content)
df['Occurence'] = pd.Series(output_content.count(i) for i in keywords)
print(df)
```

```
  Keyword  Occurence
0  Goulds         47
1    Pump         81
2    http         15
```

I used a generator expression in place of the `count_of_occ` list, but you can also do the following:

```py
count_of_occ = [0 for i in keywords]
for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
    if keyword in output_content:
        count_of_occ[i] += output_content.count(keyword)
df['Occurence'] = pd.Series(count_of_occ, index=df.index)
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you. As a side note to your example, though, I realized that it was actually even multiplying the total number of occurrences by 3. For example, my original script showed 429, occurrences. The new script shows that the total across all keywords is 143, which is 1/3 of 429.